# I have no publications or professional experience, will my short CV look bad for US graduate admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, cv

Generally, it is a requirement to add CV in the graduate application, where they suggest to add professional experiences, journal articles info and research works details.

The problem is that, I don't have any journal papers and also I didn't do job. I did a project in masters and I have experience to do thesis works. Therefore, all the  information is contained within one page in the CV.  Will it be considered as a bad CV as it doesn't have a lot of info as they expect?

NOTE: I didn't add any test score on the CV because I wrote these info on the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely isn't unheard of to have a short resume/CV coming out of undergrad. Also, having just one page is perfectly fine and is actually about what I would expect from most people.

If you must fill space, I usually recommend adding course projects or personal projects relevant to your field.

Answer (score 0):

CV's come in many formats.  Some will list "research experience", where you can list your supervisor and describe the project you worked on.  You may also want to list workshops or training you have taken outside of your academic coursework.  Awards and other recognitions should also be added.  I would suggest that you search online for examples of CV's or ask someone from your cohort for an example of their CV to get more ideas and examples.  The idea of the CV is that it is a place to elaborate on achievements and experiences that would otherwise not be noted in your application.